# Is it possible to open modal in angular 6 without using material only bootstrap?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I have left bar component. Inside that component I have button for open modal. How can I open modal from that button but not to open it inside that component?

Answer (score 3):

You can add your `modal` code inside your parents `.component.html` so that it is available on the whole page.

For [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) (for example) this should be look like this:

```
<ng-template #myModal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        ...
</ng-template>
```

In your child's component (your left bar component) you can now add an outputs that open's this modal:

```
@Output() openmodal: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

By pressing your button

```
<button (click)="openMyOpen()">Open Modal</button>
```

you can trigger the output

```
openMyOpen(): void {
    this.openmodal.emit(true);
}
```

In your parent's component you can receive this output if configured

```
<left-bar (openmodal)="open($event, )"></left-bar>
```

And open your modal in this component

```
@ViewChild('myModal') myModal: NgbModal;

open(): void {
   this.modalService.open(this.myModal);
}
```

Please not that this solution uses [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) but can be adjusted by any modal you want to use.